# Copied answers: plagiarism check before uploading an answer and credit to the original answerer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, plagiarism

There have been instances where I have come across a couple of answers that have been exactly copied from another user's answer including code, to similar type of question. I don't think there is anything wrong with learning and then answering similar question yourself later,
but I feel there must be an acknowledgement given to the original answerer in any form, be it reputation, if the answer gets selected later, or batch or literally anything that provides some credit to the original answerer.

Also I don't see any reason how completely copying an answer is justified.

Comment: When you have 15 rep, you can flag such answers with custom flag (and provide all the relevant information) if you *really* think that the content has been plagiarised. Note that if the content is copied [from [main]]) *and* includes citation, then that is perfectly fine per the CC by-SA licence.

Comment: I've edited out the commentary about potentially adding screenshots. You can still go ahead and add screenshots if you want, but I would suggest not doing so unless the examples provide some context that is necessary to understand the question. Publicly exposing users for possible infractions is unproductive in general. It's generally better to flag such behavior, as Larnu mentioned.

Comment: *"I don't see any reason how completely copying an answer is justified."* I don't, either, and neither do any of the moderators. Plagiarism violates our rules here, so if you see a post that is plagiarized either from Stack Overflow itself or from another site, please raise a moderator flag on that post.